# ionic3 with cordova broadcaster plugin not work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I use the latest ionic3, with an Android mobile scanner pda, the scan result will be broadcasted, so I use the plugin 'cordova-broadcaster' to receive the result in ionic app as the official doc example, but the event addEventListener not work, without any error or exception, I have tried many times, even write an Android native app send local broadcast, has anyone success call the plugin or give me an example, thanks

Comment: Yeah, I am getting the same. Did you get any solution?

Comment: To help **cordova-broadcaster** setup I’ve created a [sample project](https://github.com/bsorrentino/ionic-broadcaster-sample) that shows how to use it